# Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'. Java compiler is not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-test, java-home

I am trying to run Spring tests for the first time. After finishing writing them, and typing .\gradelw.bat test into the terminal I recieve such an error -

> Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'. Java compiler is not available. Please check that C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-17.0.6.10-hotspot contains a valid JDK installation.

After trying to set org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-19 in gradle.properties I am just recieving an error of an illigal symbol ':' in gradle.properties line 2

Also tried setting JAVA_HOME in Environment Variables but nothing's changed.

Would love to recieve any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding JAVA_HOME to Environment Variables in Windows worked, then I had to reload gradle